# Multiple Buttons in Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, xcode8

I have three buttons namely B0, B1 and B2 in a custom TableViewCell, I have set that three buttons color is blue color.
In navigation bar there is addition button for increase cell number, when you tap that addition button cell number will increase and tableview will reload.
By default `numberOfRowsInSection` returning 1 and default selected button "B0" is color green.

Now, if you select B1, it will change to green color and remaining two will be blue color, if you select B2, then B2 will turn into green and vice versa.

But when you increasing number of cell by clicking that Addition button in navigation bar, the three buttons in cell 1 showing blue colors, and in cell 0 it is showing as we have set before increasing. As shown in image bellow:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm not able to think that logic, that how to make like cell 0 before any addition the cell.

In every cell and every cell buttons must be selected as radio button there, and i failed to make that possible.

here is my code.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TableViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{

    IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewTest;

    int rows;
    int selectedTag;

}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    rows = 1;
    tableViewTest.delegate = self;
    tableViewTest.dataSource = self;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return rows;

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableViewCell"];

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {

        cell.btnB0.tag = indexPath.row;
        cell.btnB1.tag = indexPath.row+1;
        cell.btnB2.tag = indexPath.row+2;
    }
    else{

        cell.btnB0.tag = indexPath.row*3;
        cell.btnB1.tag = indexPath.row*3+1;
        cell.btnB2.tag = indexPath.row*3+2;
    }

    cell.btnB0.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    cell.btnB1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    cell.btnB2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    if (cell.btnB0.tag == selectedTag) {

        cell.btnB0.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        cell.btnB1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        cell.btnB2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
    else if (cell.btnB1.tag == selectedTag) {

        cell.btnB0.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        cell.btnB1.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        cell.btnB2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
    else if (cell.btnB2.tag == selectedTag) {

        cell.btnB0.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        cell.btnB1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        cell.btnB2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }

    [cell.btnB0 addTarget:self action:@selector(cellRadioButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.btnB1 addTarget:self action:@selector(cellRadioButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.btnB2 addTarget:self action:@selector(cellRadioButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}

-(void)cellRadioButtonAction: (UIButton *)sender{

    NSLog(@"%d",(int)sender.tag);

    selectedTag = (int)sender.tag;

    [tableViewTest reloadData];
}

- (IBAction)barBtnAddCell:(id)sender {

    rows++;

    [tableViewTest reloadData];
}


@end
```

Any help will be appreciable.
Thanks.

Comment: @PhaniRaghu How to hold the index if you select B1 suppose.

Comment: @PhaniRaghu Yes, i'm able to get the cell index as well with bottun tag, now what to do..?

Comment: Yup do one thing. First create methods for buttons. Once user selects the buttons. Get that id and hold it in an array. Then reload table view. In cellForRowAtIndexPath, first check array count. If count is there then check index. If current index is matched then set button colour as you want.

Comment: Sorry I didn't seen your code. You already implemented methods for buttons. You did almost correct. Just need to change logic in CellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @PhaniRaghu I tried that for whole day and failed, what i did is took nsmutableorederedset instead of nsmutablearray, and keeps the selected button tag under the indexpath.row as keyvalue, thought it will solve the equation but it getting complex and more complex instead. Finally thought, i will take that value from json, and it will be more easy. Thanks for your suggestion by the way.. :)